# How to save | symbol in joomla configuration

Tags: php, joomla

In Joomla Plugin configuration, the value likes `10001|A825FCD`, `10001|A82CCCD` are not saved when I click on save button. It is due to the symbol `|`.

Anybody has any solution for this problem?

Comment: Which plugin are you talking about? Give all details like plugin name, the text fields where you are entering these codes etc.

Comment: I am talking about a payment plugin in joomla site.

Comment: I am integrating adyen payment gateway in joomla virtuemart site. In adyen payment configuration settings I need to take Client Encryption Key of adyen account from the admin. And this key contains symbol | , due to which key is not saving in the configuration.

Comment: Are you developing adyen payment gateway yourself? I didnt find this gateway in virtuemart gateway list.

Comment: I am just integrating adyen in joomla virtuemart site.

Answer (score 0):

There can be many cases, depends on what the exact issue is:

1. ***PHP Version Issue with VM:*** Check the PHP version where you hosted your web application. The Virtuemart Plugins are not storing values with PHP 5.2 version. I have personally faced this issue a few months ago.
2. ***Retrieving the variable value from POST:*** Check the method used to retrieve the value from the post in the plugin code. It should pass the 'raw' as the third argument to get RAW data from the request.
3. ***Storage Container DataType in MYSQL*** Check the datatype where value of configuration saved. It should be appropriate to store UTF-8 strings.

Comment: If you have worked on a joomla virtuemart site, then only you can answer............Issue is this that In vmpayment plugin configuration the symbol '|' is not showing as saved.....whereas if we check in the database the value is stored there.